# Should I avoid using jQuery in Chrome extension's content script?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

If the page comes with jQuery, then it will have two jQuery scripts. If another extension loads jQuery as well, then there will be three jQuery scripts on the same page. I feel it's kind of crazy. What do you think? Thanks.

This is the paragraph that left me the impression above.

> If your extension needs to interact with web pages, then it needs a
>   content script. A content script is some JavaScript that executes in
>   the context of a page that's been loaded into the browser. **Think of a
>   content script as part of that loaded page, not as part of the
>   extension it was packaged with (its parent extension).**

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch

Comment: Bear in mind that jQuery itself has *numerous* different versions and, while designed to work with out libraries [that define '$'] is unlikely to be designed to work with different versions of itself.  In a chrome extension, can you check if jquery is already loaded?

Comment: So the content script can't call javascript functions in the original page. But it can manipulate DOM elements on the original page.

In other words, the content script can't see the jQuery in the original page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Content Script is injected into the page, it **has** access to the DOM of the page, but **has not** access to page's JS objects. And vice versa, the page cannot access Content Script's variables.

When you inject jQuery via Content Script, it populates extension's `window` object (with 2 properties - `window.$` and `window.jQuery`). And only your extension has access to it.

**Original page's `window` object might have its own jQuery, and they will not conflict with each other.**

For debugging purpose Chrome allows you to switch JS context in Developer Tools:

[image]